# How to give active class on NavItem on browser back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my application I am using react router 3
For navigation menu i have used

```
<nav>
    <NavItem> </NavItem>
</nav>
```

It is working fine on click of nav menu but when going back using browser back, the url changed but the active class does not applied.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain how it should be done generally, not framework specific. you can implement the same in any framework after that

in order to make stateful navigation, You can take advantage of query parameters. 
all you have to do on click of the nav you have to append some value to the query parameters which will identify its uniqueness.

and on the component initialization you have to read the query params and programmatically select that tab.(apply css class to it)

For example, you have:

```
url:somedomain.com/home -- this is where you have navigation
NavItem1 href="somedomain.com/home?nav=tab1"
NavItem2 href="somedomain.com/home?nav=tab2"
NavItem3 href="somedomain.com/home?nav=tab3"
```

when the component initializes , you have to read the query params if exists and give the appropriate class to the particular `NavItem`